# awk - вывести все совпадения в строке

Tags: html, bash, awk

Есть такая строка:

```
<tr class="coin" data-symbol="BTC"><td align=center class="price"><span>49267138</span></td><td align=center class="change"> <span style="color: #60c68b;"><i class="fa fa-caret-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> 06</span></td><td align=center class="daily-amount market-cap">13856102009500</td><td align=center class="daily-amount supply">BTC 1669466200</td><td align=center class="daily-amount volume">340830000000</td></tr>
```

Команда:

```
awk -F'<td[^>]*>(<span>)?|(</?span>)?</td>' '$2~/[0-9]/{print $2+0}'
```

Выводит `49267138`

Взял отсюда:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25358698/bash-parse-html

Так вот вопрос, как вывести не первое совпадение, а все?

Comment: Не используйте awk! Есть нормальные парсеры XML и биндинги к соответствующим языкам программирования, например, lxml в python. Соответственно задача сводится к 3 строчнику, где в цикле просто печатается, что нужно по паттерну XPath.

Comment: Почитайте второй ответ по вами же приведенной ссылке, там и комментарии некоторые хороши. Поставил там плюсики от себя.

Comment: _It is **impossible** to correctly parse XML using regex, not just difficult. ...Just because it works in this case does not mean it is correct. The problem is that it looks correct and this is why so many people try to use regex for XML parsing - And because that is incorrect and opens you up to a world of pain so many people advice against it. Rightfully so._ via @dirkk

Comment: Добрый день! @Nikolay Petrov тут проблема в том что awk как бы дробит строку на столбцы и загоняет их в переменные $i которые можно напечатать обращаясь в ним (напр. $1, $2 и т.д.). В вашем конкретном случае строка одна и awk разбил ее на эти столбцы используя вашу regex маску. Если бы строк было больше, они были бы однотипными и их можно было бы regex выражением раздробить на части, тогда ваша переменная $2 была бы равна второму "столбцу" в каждой из этих строк и вернула бы значения найденные по маске в каждой строке. Надеюсь понятно объяснил )

Comment: @СергейГамов хорошо, а как тогда вывести не всю совпавшую строку, а только совпадение с регуляркой? То есть у меня выводит "&#8381 476,785.19", а мне надо только "476,785.19"

Comment: @Nikolay Petrov к примеру так: echo "&#8381 476,785.19" | awk '{print $2}'